# Angular, Redux, ES6, Unit Testing Controllers

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, redux

Our Angular project moved to ES6 and Reduxjs, and now I am struggling to get controller unit tests working. Specifically, I  cant seem to mock correctly when it comes to the class constructor. From what i have researched, i cant spyOn an ES6 class constructor, so i need to mock its dependencies and also accommodate the binding to lexical 'this' that ngRedux.connect() facilitates.

My test makes it to the connect function in the constructor, and then gives me the error: "'connect' is not a function"

I think i may have several things wrong here. If i comment out the connect line in the constructor, it'll get to my runOnLoad function and the error will tell me that fromMyActions isnt a function. this is because the redux connect function binds the actions to 'this', so given these issues, I take it I cant mock redux unless i provide its implementation. any advice? I am relatively new to angular as well - and my weakest area is unit testing and DI.

Here is my module and controller:

```
export const myControllerModule = angular.module('my-controller-module',[]);

export class MyController {

constructor($ngRedux, $scope) {
'ngInject';

  this.ngRedux = $ngRedux;
  const unsubscribe = this.ngRedux.connect(this.mapState.bind(this), myActions)(this);
  $scope.$on('$destroy', unsubscribe);
  this.runOnLoad();
}

mapState(state) {
  return {};
}

runOnLoad() {
   this.fromMyActions(this.prop);
  }
}

myControllerModule 
  .controller(controllerId, MyController
  .directive('myDirective', () => {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      controller: controllerId,
      templateUrl: htmltemplate
      bindToController: true,
      scope: {
        data: '=',
        person: '='
      }
    };
  });

export default myControllerModule.name;
```

and my test:

```
import {myControllerModule,MyController} from './myController';
import 'angular-mocks/angular-mocks';

describe('test', () => {

  let controller, scope;

  beforeEach(function() {

let reduxFuncs = {
  connect: function(){}
}

angular.mock.module('my-controller-module', function ($provide) {
  $provide.constant('$ngRedux',reduxFuncs);
});

angular.mock.inject(function (_$ngRedux_, _$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
  scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
  redux = _$ngRedux_;

  var scopeData = {
    data : {"test":"stuff"},
    person : {"name":"thatDude"}
  } ;
        scope.$digest();

        controller = _$controller_(MyController, {
        $scope: scope,
        $ngRedux: redux
      }, scopeData);
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: 1. where is the function declaration for fromMyActions? 2. when you are mocking controller dependencies, you can just create a mock object and send it to $controller constructor. You don't need to add the mock object at the $provide level.

Comment: myActions are imported. i omitted that line. that part should work fine, its the 'this' ref that it chokes on. I have tried simply passing the dependencies into the new object, but that didnt work in the spec file. i'll try that again and see if i can get it to work.

Comment: passing redux to the constructor does not work. I am not sure why. Does anyone have an example of doing this? the ngRedux folks should have one - as i would assume that testing controllers is critical aspect of an ngRedux project. with Redux, controllers should be thin - just invoking actions from view events, but they still need to be tested.

Comment: Curious -- why can't you spy on a constructor in es6?  `sinon.spy(MyClass, 'constructor')` doesn't work?  **edit**: no, but I guess it can be done [this](http://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2013/06/10/mocking-calls-to-a-class-constructor-in-javascript/) way.

Comment: I have no particular problem to test controller with ngRedux and reselect, using $controller  : real example here: https://github.com/CaliOpen/caliopen.web-client-ng/blob/master/src/js/directive/discussions.js and https://github.com/CaliOpen/caliopen.web-client-ng/blob/master/test/unit/directive/discussions-spec.js

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind Redux is that most of your controllers have no, or very little logic. The logic will be in action creators, reducers and selectors mostly.
In the example you provide, most of your code is just wiring things. 
I personally don't test wiring, because it adds very little value, and those kinds of test are generally very brittle.

With that said, if you want to test your controllers nonetheless you have two options:

- Use functions instead of classes for controllers. For most controllers using a class adds no real value. Instead use a function, and isolate the logic you want to test in another pure function. You can then test this function without even needing mocks etc.
- If you still want to use classes, you will need to use a stub of ng-redux, (something like this: https://gist.github.com/wbuchwalter/d1448395f0dee9212b70 (it's in TypeScript))

And use it like this:

```
let myState = {
  someProp: 'someValue'
}

let ngReduxStub;
let myController;
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject($injector => {
  ngReduxStub = new NgReduxStub();

  //how the state should be initially
  ngReduxStub.push(myState);
  myController = new MyController(ngReduxStub, $injector.get('someOtherService');
}));
```

Note: I personnaly don't use mapDispatchToProps (I expose my action creators through an angular service), so the stub does not handle actions, but it should be easy to add.

Comment: thanks for the stub ref; I think we're got a step further here. I created an ES6 version of the stub which i will post here when everything works correctly. The issue i have now is that the test will not bind to directive scope. The controller itself, outside of the unit test works fine, but when i make a call, for example, to this.person.firstName, i get an error stating that person is undefined. this occurs when i call a class function that takes directive scope as params. So this doesnt appear to be an ngRedux issue, but still fundamental to my tests. an updated example would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting the following error while trying to write tests using Karma and Jasmine:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 
$ngRedux.connect(function (state) { ({}, state.editAudience); }, _actions2.default)')
```

I managed to make it work by roughly translating wbuch's stub into es6 and using it like this:

```
angular.mock.module( $provide => {
    ngReduxStub = new NgReduxStub()
    ngReduxStub.push(myState)
    const dependencies = ['$scope', '$ngRedux']
    dependencies.forEach( dependency => {
        if(dependency =='$ngRedux') { return $provide.value('$ngRedux', ngReduxStub)}
        return $provide.value(dependency, {})
    })
})

angular.mock.inject( ($compile, $rootScope, $componentController) => {
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
    ctrl = $componentController('csEditAudience', {$scope: scope}, {})
})
```

[Here's my version of the stub](https://gist.github.com/kareniel/ac08b1b4e7c817583da649452a8839fe)

I hope this helps!